# Подскажите, чего может жрать много процессора на сервере

Tags: php, mysql, веб-программирование, laravel, веб-сервер

```
public function allusedgoods(Request $request)
{
    /**
     * @var $tasks Collection
     */
    $tasks = Task::with('user', 'director', 'deletedBy');
    if (Auth::user()->hasRole(User::ROLE_LEADER)) {

        $myadmins = User::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
        //$ids = $myadmins->pluck('id')->withTrashed();
        $ids = User::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->withTrashed()->pluck('id');

        $ids[] = Auth::user()->id;
        $tasks = $tasks->whereIn('director_id', $ids);
    } elseif (Auth::user()->hasRole(User::ROLE_ADMIN) || Auth::user()->hasRole(User::ROLE_ADMIN_READONLY)) {
        $myadmins = User::where('user_id', Auth::user()->user_id)->get();
        $ids = $myadmins->pluck('id');
        $ids[] = Auth::user()->user_id;
        $tasks = $tasks->whereIn('director_id', $ids);
    } else {
        $admin = DB::table('users')
            ->where('id', Auth::user()->user_id)
            ->first();

        $leader = DB::table('users')
            ->where('id', $admin->user_Id)
            ->first();

        $tasks = $tasks->where('director_id', $leader->id);
    }

    $tasks = $tasks->where('status', 'done');


    if ($request->has('status')) {
        if ('not_accepted' === $request->get('status')) {
            $tasks->withoutTrashed();
        }


        if ($request->get('status') == 'not_done') {
            $tasks = $tasks->where(function ($query) {
                return $query->where('status', 'not_done')
                    ->whereBetween('updated_at', [
                        Carbon::now()->startOfDay(),
                        Carbon::now()->endOfDay()
                    ]);
            });
        } else {
            $tasks = $tasks->where('status', $request->get('status'));
        }
    }

    if ($request->has('date_filter')) {
        if ($request->has('date_start') && $request->has('date_end')) {
            $tasks = $tasks->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                return $query->whereBetween('updated_at', [
                    Carbon::createFromTimestamp($request->input('date_start')),
                    Carbon::createFromTimestamp($request->input('date_end')),
                ]);
            });
        } elseif ($request->has('date_day')) {
            $tasks = $tasks->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                return $query->whereBetween('updated_at', [
                    Carbon::createFromTimestamp($request->input('date_day'))->startOfDay(),
                    Carbon::createFromTimestamp($request->input('date_day'))->endOfDay(),
                ]);
            });
        }
    }

    $tasks = $tasks->where('check_minibar', '1');        
    $tasks = $tasks->whereNotNull('executor_comment');

    $tasks = $tasks->withTrashed()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate($request->get('per-page', 100000000));


    return [
        'success' => true,
        'message' => false,
        'payload' => [
            'usedGoods' => $tasks
        ]
    ];

}
```

Comment: Скорее всего БД из-за запроса съедает много ресурсов. Сколько записей в таблице tasks?

Comment: @YuriyProkopets 40 тыс. а какой выход?)

Comment: можно оптимизировать запрос. Для этого сначала нужно узнать сам запрос. Например в MySQL есть возможность логировать запросы, которые выполняются дольше заданого времени (https://ruhighload.com/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+slow+log+%D0%B2+mysql%3F)

Comment: И еще вопрос. Сколько в итоге выводится записей в `usedGoods`?

Comment: @YuriyProkopets все что получают с сервера. Там например статистика за год может выводится.

Comment: А что slowlog показывает?

Comment: @YuriyProkopets у меня шаред сервер, получить словлоги нет возможности(

Comment: Установи Laravel Debuger Bar там отобразиться кол-во запросов и время исполнения. Сможешь понять что долго отрабатывает.